# Excel VBA evaluate string from cell as formula with a variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have spent hours on this and have found related questions but I have not found an answer that works, so I do not believe this is a duplicate.

I have a string in a cell that represents a simple formula a variable in it.  That variable will be pre-defined.  Then I need to evaluate the string.  I cannot get the cell value to evaluate.  The string itself evaluates in the immediate window but the exact same cell value string does not:

```
?myVar
 1 
?[M115].Value
"0.1*" & myVar & "*(0.2+0.3*" & myVar & "/.4)"
?Evaluate("0.1*" & myVar & "*(0.2+0.3*" & myVar & "/.4)")
 0.095 
?Evaluate([M115].Value)
Error 2029
```

My best guess in the variable is not getting evaluated since I can replace the myVar with a 1 and it works.  I've tried all manner of triple quoting and that doesn't work either.  How can I accomplish this seemingly simple thing?  I have tried wrapping in subs and functions like so:

```
Function ev(r As Range, ByVal myVar As Double) As Variant
    Debug.Print myVar
    Debug.Print r.value
    ev = Evaluate(r.value)
End Function

?ev([M115], 1)
 1 
 "0.1*" & myVar & "*(0.2+0.3*" & myVar & "/.4)"
Error 2029

myVar=1
?Evaluate("0.1*" & myVar & "*(0.2+0.3*" & myVar & "/.4)")
0.095
```

What am I overlooking?  Thanks.

Comment: Try to declare the variable as  Name under Name Manager in Excel and remove the double quotes and &. If myVar as Name is set to 1 and cell holds string myVar + 2 it should evaluate to 3 I believe. Give it a try.

Comment: That actually works, thank you. That suggests that when using Evaluate(), what I thought was a variable is actually a range.   That is sneaky.

However, I really can't use a named cell for my particular variable as the source of the value will be very dynamic.   Unless I have to put up with having some named cells somewhere that I continually overwrite.  I guess I'll try that and see how it goes.

Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: There could be another option, use plain string instead of name e.g. cell holds myvar+2 (myvar is not declared anywhere, it's just plain text) Now in your VBA Function pass actual variable value and replace myvar with that variable and  evaluate the resulting expression.

Comment: That sounds like what I really want, but I can't get it to work.  Do you have an example?  There must be something I am still overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution and revert back if it works for you.
Press ALT + F11 to open VBA Editor. Insert a Module and paste the following UDF into it.

```
Public Function test(r As Range, myvar As Double) As Double
Z = r.Formula
Z = Replace(Z, "myvar", myvar)
test = Evaluate(Z)
End Function
```

Now your expression in Excel cells should not hold any characters that are not part of the formula like & " etc. It should hold plain formula with static name and keep the name constant thruout and case sensitive.

e.g. myvar + 3 here myvar is just static text,not declared anywhere.
Use the function and pass the cell as range and variable value as double to it.
No much validations are in place, passing multi dimensional array could result into an error here. See the below screenshot. Give it a try and check if this meets your requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough cred on superuser to upvote, I just linked my stackoverflow account today.  However, that answer was close enough to get unstuck.  Here is what is working:

```
Public Function evtest(r As Range, myVar As Double) As Variant
    Dim z As Variant
    z = r.formula
    z = Replace(z, "myVar", myVar)
    Debug.Print z
    evtest = Evaluate(z)
End Function
```

Now I think I have something to work with

```
?[M113].Value
0.1*myVar*(0.2+0.3*myVar/.4)
?evtest([M113], 1)
0.1*1*(0.2+0.3*1/.4)
 0.095
```

If I find something need modifying I will update this answer.  Thank you very much.

**EDIT**:  I have made it a bit more universal:

```
Function evtest(r As Range, myVarName As String, myVarValue As Double) As Variant
    Dim z As Variant
    z = r.formula
    z = Replace(z, myVarName, myVarValue)
    Debug.Print z
    evtest = Evaluate(z)
End Function
```

Now use like so:

```
?[M113].Value
0.1*myVar*(0.2+0.3*myVar/.4)
?TEST.evtest([M113], "myVar", 1.5)
0.1*1.5*(0.2+0.3*1.5/.4)
 0.19875
```

Hope this helps someone else.